# html: embed music player from reverbnation.com gives different errors

Tags: html, validation, iframe, markup

On a webpage-project, I want to embed a music player provided by reverbnation.

As you can see [here](http://www.reverbnation.com/rozbub?page_view_source=facebook_app) (click on 'share', then 'embed' and finally 'get Code'), an iframe is provided.

However, running the w3c validator, it seems having trouble with the `&` character, as you can see [here](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://magnavoce.ch/rozbub/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.3). How can this errors be eliminated? Why are these characters even considered as errors? Btw the player is working fine. There were more errors concerning whitespaces in the URL, which were easy to fix.

The next stage of error is an `unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL (...). Domains, protocols and ports must match`. I do not exactly understand how to fix such errors, as I don't understand the error itself. Is it in general a bad manner to work with iframes (as I got a lot of such errors with different widgets like facebook)?